# ASP.NET C# listing directory structure into a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

I want to list all the folders and their subfolders and theirs till reaching to deepest folder.

I have written a method like this:

```
public void scanFolders(string path)
{
    foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        listBox_Folders.Items.Add(dir.Name);
    }
}
```

This brings me all the folders and subfolders. It is OK

But I need a little different solution. I want to list subfolders of a folder just beneath its parent starting with a hyphen (-).

It should look like

```
<select>
    <option>folder1</option>
    <option>-subfolder11</option>
    <option>folder2</option>
    <option>-subfolder21</option>
    <option>-subfolder22</option>
</select>
```

What I have is

```
<select>
    <option>folder1</option>
    <option>folder2</option>
    <option>subfolder11</option>
    <option>subfolder21</option>
    <option>subfolder22</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why can't you try to load on demand, sub folder data when user click on the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion

```
    private void ScanFolder(String prefix, String path)
    {
        foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            listBox_Folders.Items.Add(prefix + dir.Name);

            ScanFolder(prefix + "-", dir.FullName);
        }
    }
```

First call like `ScanFolder(String.Empty, 'yourpathhere');`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a sort by `FullName` before iterating.

```
    foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo(path)
        .GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .OrderBy(d => d.FullName))
    {
        listBox_Folders.Items.Add(dir.Name);
    }
```

Comment: OrderBy is not accepted. I mean it is underlined with red line. Could it be a version issue? I use VS2010.

Comment: @Please check if you have System.Linq namespace included